# Child components and DI context

Tags: angular

I have an app that has various types of searches - however a lot of the functionality between these searches is the same, additionally the view is almost the same with the exception of a few strings (panel titles etc.).

I have a base SearchComponent and a Specialized search component.  The Specialized search components instantiates the base SearchComponent in the markup and sets the appropriate inputs.

Each specialized search component uses a different search strategy i.e. service instance and method and mapping of the results.

Currently I am binding a function reference to the parent when instantiating the base component so that the parent function can be called.  However it looks like the DI context is different so it complains that my injected service in the parent is not found.

How can I solve this?

Example:

In search-base.ts:

```
  @Input() execSearchFn: (query) => Observable<any>;
  @Input() mapTableDataFn: (i: any) => any;

executeSearch(e) {  // Triggered by some event
  this.execSearchFn(e.query);  // delegate to parent for specialized search
}
```

In xyz-search.html:

```
   <app-search-base #appSearchBase
    searchTitle="XYZ Search"
    [execSearchFn]="execSearch"
    [mapTableDataFn]="mapTableData">
  </app-search-base>
```

In xyz-search.ts:

```
constructor(private xyzService: XYZService) {}

execSearch(query: string) {
 return this.xyzService.search(query);  // does not work! xyzService is undefined!
}
```

This works fine, the function in the parent is called but it cannot find any of the injected attributes.

ERROR is "cannot read property search of undefined".  Sure enough xyzService is injected and defined in the constructor but because the call context is from the base component it's undefined in the execSearch function.

The functionality I am aiming for is similar to defining an abstract method in the base class and a subclass defining the exact behavior for that abstract method.  However Angular does not allow Abstract components so have to use the above workaround.  I can in fact create a regular abstract base class but then I cannot re-use the markup.  I need to re-use both base functionality and base markup.

I am guessing the best way to do this would be to Emit an execute event (rather than using a function reference) and then send the results back via an Input()??  This just sounds too convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this was a hard one to understand. Just for clarifictaion that I got it right: you're trying to get an action performed by a child component (here the search-base) and want to react to it in the parent component (here your xyz-search).

This is usually a good example for an `output` binding on a function. You are currently providing a function as an input variable, giving code to your child component instead of emitting a call as an output from it. This is kind of the dirty way to do it and it has limits. And you found one, because just giving code will lose context.

So here's what I would do. I'd change your functions from input to output, which  can be done in a few easy steps. Here's the parent component.

```
<app-search-base #appSearchBase
    searchTitle="XYZ Search"
    (onExecSearch)="execSearch($event)"
    [mapTableDataFn]="mapTableData">
 </app-search-base>
```

We only have to use parentheses and call the parents `execSearch` function with the $event parameter here (this is crucial, so don't forget that). The parentheses change the binding type from `input` to `output`. I renamed the child function to `onExecSearch` to make it clearer that it is called when something happens.

Now in the child component we have to use the given output function through an output event emitter. This is a common angular pattern if you want to call it like that.

```
@Output() onExecSearch: new EventEmitter<string>();

executeSearch(e) {   
  this.onExecSearch.emit(e.query); 
}
```

We can call the provided output function of the parent by emitting a value of the correct type on the `onExecSearch` emitter. Your parent `execSearch` function is **bound** to the emitter and is therefore called when `onExecSearch` calls its `emit` function, but this way it will do it with the correct context.

> The child component exposes an EventEmitter property with which it
>   emits events when something happens. The parent binds to that event
>   property and reacts to those events.

Your XYZ-search.ts doesn't even change, it should get called correctly.

For more information, check [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) tutorial, they can probably explain it a bit better than me.

Comment: thanks! I was thinking that this is my only option, I was trying to use an easier way because I would have to monitor the Input() using ngOnChanges

Comment: one of the drawbacks of having the output (execution) and input (results) separated is that I lose the context of the original event in the ngOnChanges.